Possessed boy with supernatural powers
A long time ago I watched a TV series or movie where a kid is possessed and starts murdering people. The kid has supernatural powers to move things with his mind. For example he moves a scarf around a neck and into a bus door, so the victim dies.
At the end, it is clear that he is possessed by someone who is murdered (drown in aquarium) and wanted revenge. Anyone?

It's an episode from the 1st season of the X-Files, "Born Again" which aired April 22, 1994.
Episode Summary:

After a detective and his former partner die in unexplained
  circumstances, the accidents are linked to a little girl who witnessed
  both deaths and Mulder believes that she may be the reincarnation of a
  policeman murdered by his colleagues.

Scarf Scene 

That night, Felder gets off a bus, but his scarf catches in the door as
  it drives off. The driver tries to brake, but the bus inexplicably
  continues to accelerate, strangling Felder as Michelle watches from
  inside the bus.

(from a imdb.com review)

A man WHO ALSO works at the precinct leaves to get off a bus, but this
  "ghostly power" lifts the scarf back into the path of the closing bus
  door. The bus driver notices this after a few seconds and tries to
  stop, but the ghostly power is pushing on the accelerator. Eventually
  the driver gains control again when the man dies. For some odd reason
  the bus driver didn't question the fact that the little girl was also
  on the bus staring menacingly at the dragging man.

Murder by Aquarium:

Michelle undergoes a session of regression hypnosis, where she claims
  to be twenty-four years old. She suddenly starts screaming in panic
  about someone trying to kill her, and the session is ended. Mulder
  reviews the video of the session, and is convinced that the girl is
  the reincarnation of Morris, having been conceived right around the
  time the detective was murdered. The tape contains a brief section of
  static noise just before Michelle begins screaming, which Mulder has
  an expert clean up. The noise is found to contain a grainy image of
  what appears to be a fish tank ornament of a man in an atmospheric
  diving suit. Meanwhile, Scully has tracked down Morris' autopsy
  findings, which show the presence of salt water in his respiratory
  tract, indicating he died of drowning. The agents realise from these
  findings that Morris was drowned in the exotic fish tank in Fiore's
  house.
Rushing to Fiore's house, Mulder and Scully find Michelle using
  telekinetic powers to try to kill Fiore. They prevent her from doing
  so, and Fiore confesses that he, Felder and Barbala had stolen a large
  sum of money, intending to keep it safe for ten years before claiming
  it. Morris learned of their plan and threatened to report them for it,
  and was killed to silence him. However, Fiore maintains that he never
  wanted to see Morris dead. Michelle uses her powers to destroy the
  fish-tank, but spares Fiore after hearing pleas from Anita. Later,
  Fiore pleads guilty to charges of murder and grand larceny, whilst
  Michelle seemingly recovers and goes on to become a normal little
  girl.


Yep, that's the one! Always thougt it was X-files, but it has been a while. Thank you, Thank you, Thank you

@DennisPettinga If this is the correct answer, please mark it as such by clicking on the tick mark to the left of Trish's post.
